# How do I display an image within the HiddenField asp.NET field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hiddenfield

*Note:* I'm just an lowly intern here, so be nice :) I've spent some time researching before asking but didn't find the answer I'm looking for.

Suppose I have a line in my .aspx file like so:

```
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenfield" Value=??? >
```

What should I put for the value if I would like this hidden field to display a .png image when shown?

Sorry I can't give much more detail, I don't want to violate my company's policies. If you need any more information, let me know and I'll try to give an example.

Comment: you're not giving much detail but I would recommend doing a google search on how to display image within a Hidden Field.. start there and do some more work on your end..

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after - but hiddenfields don't show images? Image controls show images and can be hidden.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you just want to hide the image use a div that is not visbile and visibility to true when needed

Comment: A hidden field, contrary to what you might expect does not hide anything really unless you encrypt it. So putting an image there does not really make a lof sense? You really need to explain or give an example of what you are trying to achive

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display an image, you should use the Image control. 
If you want to hide it, wrap it in a div and set the visibility to hidden. For example:

```
<div id="divHidden" style="visibility: hidden">
    <asp:Image runat="server" AlternateText="this is an image" ImageUrl="/img/myimage.gif"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I know how to display an image, but I want the image within the hidden field. Do you know how this is done?

Comment: @Haleyo the Hiddenfield will only hold text data. If you want to store an image in there you will have to encode it using base64 encoding. If you let us know what you are trying to achieve perhaps we can help

Comment: Thanks, Donal. If I can't have images within hiddenfields I'm going to have to redesign the whole page because they used hiddenfields like crazy and it all needs to be replaced with hidden images. I think this answers my question though.

Comment: I know how to do this with image or div, but I was just hoping there was a way to do this with hiddenfield (without using inefficient base64 encoding) because they like their pages to be of a similar format, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Haleyo ok, the only thing you could do is store the path to the image in the Value attribute of the HiddenField control.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can save image path only in hidden field using this.

`<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenfield" Value="/img/myimage.png" >`

And later retrieve that using javscript `document.getElementById("hiddenfield").value` , and set that path to actual `img` element if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use:

```
<asp:Image ID="myImage" ImageUrl="myimage.png" Visible="false" AlternateText="foo" />
```

And when you need to show it from your codeBehind:

```
myImage.Visible=true;
```